# |BUG| Ember Query Params sticks for nested routes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have an ember app with these nested routes:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('articles', {path: 'yazilar' }, function() {
        this.route('article', { path: ':id' });
    });
});
```

I use query params to filter the articles shown:

```
// `articles` route
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    tab: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('article', { tab: params.tab });
  },
  resetController: function(controller, isExiting, transition) {
    if (isExiting) {
      controller.set('tab', 'interesting');
    }
  }
});
```

and a template `articles/index.hbs` with `link-to`

```
{{#link-to 'articles' (query-params tab="newest") class="right item"}}New{{/link-to}}
{{#link-to 'articles' (query-params tab="popular") class="right item"}}Popular{{/link-to}}
```

I can switch to a new route like `articles/?tab=newest` or `articles/?tab=popular`, but when I switch to a nested route like `articles/1`, the query param persists so it becomes `articles/1/?tab=newest`.

I am also seeing this error as well, maybe related: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5070

So how to get rid of the query param when switching to a nested route in emberjs?